# CCK fields values are not coming to the body

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

Drupal 6:

I have a content type and it has multiple CCK fields: one user reference field, one node reference field, one taxonomy field, 4 text fields & 2 date fields.

It was working just fine until yesterday, but when I create content now, not even one entry is coming to the page except default boy area input & title.

It's really weird for me as this has never happened.

Does any body have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities:

1. Permission to see the fields.
2. Go to manage tab of the content type and see if you can see the fields.
3. Use `print_r($node->field_machine_readable_name);` in body or teaser.
4. Use [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module.

Comment: Permissions are there see the field and so that I am able to create the node with given fields.
In manage field also all those fields are coming.

Comment: Yes it's printing all the input values. But the thing is when we save a node and get forwarded to node page which we have created...those values are not coming on page.
Though if I visit that node again...everything is good and proper order..

Comment: Please edit your question with proper screenshots (with url etc) to help you better.